# Как установить pip для python 3.8 на Parrot OS

Tags: python

В parrot os установил python3.8 командой sudo apt-get install python3.8, как на него установить pip.

Comment: sudo apt install python3.8-pip

Comment: Просто `sudo apt install python3-pip` и должна появиться команда `pip3`

Comment: @andreymal, pip3 устанавливает пакеты в системный python3. Установленный отдельно Python 3.8 их не увидит.

Comment: @insolor в пакете python3-pip нет привязок к конкретной версии питона, он устанавливается в /usr/lib/python3/site-packages (я понятия не имею как это работает, но вот пакет именно такой)

Answer (score 0):

Кроме `pip` еще сразу можно поставить пару вещей:

```bsh
sudo apt install -y python3.8-pip python3.8-venv python3.8-dev
```

Comment: В стандартных источниках нет пакета python3.8-pip